# Could someone please explain how this break inside the two for loops work?

Tags: python, arrays

```
def findUnique(arr, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i != j:
                if arr[i] == arr[j]:
                    break 
        if j == n - 1:
            return j

    return 0
```

I am a beginner in Python. This was a program to find the unique number in a given array.
Say if
2 1 2 3 4 3 is given,
it should give 4 as the output.

The program logic is that if the n sized array has to run n times to check an element, there is no duplicate. It is a unique element.
However,
if arr[i] == arr[j]
it should break the j loop.

My confusion here is after the break, what actually happens. I know it breaks out of for loop. After that, what I gathered is it will exit out of the block of code under the line of for-j loop and checks if i is n. If not it will increment i and the same process repeats. If the i reached the last element, then it returns 0.

[image: flow]

Kindly correct.
My another doubt is directly under the

```
for j in range(n)
.
.
if j == n:
```

statement is there. When it hits the break statement in between, it should exit the for j loop. But does it check the if j == n condition? Or it goes directly for the i options?

Comment: The `break` statement always breaks out of just one single loop. If you have nested loops it will break only the inner one.

Comment: The "break" only breaks the inner (`for j`) loop.  It will then run the next iteration of the `for i` loop, just as if you had flowed out of the loop normally.

Comment: @TimRoberts Does it check for if j == n before going to the i loop?

Comment: You may want to see the code in action step by step at http://pythontutor.com.

Comment: It goes to the next statement after the loop, which is the `if j == n - 1:`.